# Any two-prong plug on any two-prong plug cable?

Tags: electrical

I've got a bunch of lamps from Europe that I want to use where we've just moved in North America. I cut off and replaced the plug on one lamp with a North American one and it works fine. I'll be doing the others. But I have an air purifier that works completely fine at 110/220V and 50/60Hz. It only uses a two prong plug. Is that likely just as easily replaceable/modifiable as lamp cables or are there gauges of wire to consider, amounts of power, different ratings of two-prong plugs, etc etc?

Comment: It'd help if we knew a little more clearly what you are trying to do. It sounds like you just want to convert all your existing appliances to work with US NEMA 5R receptacles, but it'd help if you could clarify your concerns. As it stands, it's rather broad and you're basically asking for a large portion of the NEC.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was being pretty straightforward but it's from my lack of expertise. The purifier has a two-prong european plug on the cable. I was encouraged so much here to just splice US plugs onto my european lamps that I thought, ok well what about this purifier. It's only a simple power cable as well. So, I'm asking, can it be done and is there anything to consider?
I don't like adapters, this plug doesn't sit particularly flush with the prosumer adapters I have, they get in the way of furniture, I just think they look altogether untidy. I just figure, lamps are doable why not this?

Comment: There may be 2 problems to think about. First the lamp wattage. You will need to make sure the wattage is the same or lower. The second is the polarization of the 2 prong to the lamp itself. Make sure the narrow blade of the plug goes to the center of the lamp socket. If 1 wire is silver in color and one copper the copper usually goes to the narrow blade the screw on the plug for the narrow blade is usually brass and the neutral or wider blade is usually silver. By making sure the hot is to the center pin of the lamp socket there is less chance of getting shocked. Or basic contunitity test.

Comment: All I did was cut the cord AT the plug. Then I took the plug from the hardware store and connected the wires to the inside, sealed it and plugged it in.

Answer (score 1):

First, I really don't advocate splicing new plugs onto old wires unless you *really* know what you're doing. Many of these devices likely have UL listings, which help ensure their safety in a residential context, but which also depend on the system as a whole, unmodified.

If the device says 110-240VAC and 50/60Hz, then you can simply use a plug converter, no need to splice.